# Understanding the qdbus outputs

Tags: dbus, qdbus

I would like to know more about DBus in Linux. After executing `qbus` on my terminal in Ubuntu 16.04, I see:

```
:1.0
 com.ubuntu.Upstart
:1.1
:1.11
 org.freedesktop.PowerManagement
 org.xfce.PowerManager
:1.12
:1.13
:1.15
:1.16
 ca.desrt.dconf
...
```

What does the `:1.0` mean? and why I see such a number in multiply lines ?
What I know from the manual (`--help`), the `com.ubuntu.Upstart` refers to the service name. Since, with 0 arguments, qdbus will list the services available on the bus.
So, if I run `qdbus com.ubuntu.Upstart`, it returns:

```
/
/com
/com/ubuntu
/com/ubuntu/Upstart
/com/ubuntu/Upstart/jobs
/com/ubuntu/Upstart/jobs/at_2dspi2_2dregistryd
/com/ubuntu/Upstart/jobs/dbus
...
```

My guest is that the above path is the DBus object that cannot be found in the filesystem. But, what can I interpret more details about these objects? 
Since we can create multiple buses. My last question is, how can we see a list of all available bus in a system?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From  https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html#interfaces

> When each application connects to the bus daemon, the daemon immediately assigns it a name, called the unique connection name. A unique name begins with a ':' (colon) character. These names are never reused during the lifetime of the bus daemon - that is, you know a given name will always refer to the same application. An example of a unique name might be :34-907. The numbers after the colon have no meaning other than their uniqueness.

And a little further

> Applications may ask to own additional well-known names. For example, you could write a specification to define a name called com.mycompany.TextEditor. Your definition could specify that to own this name, an application should have an object at the path /com/mycompany/TextFileManager supporting the interface org.freedesktop.FileHandler.

So something like :1.123 is just unique name but it also might be referenced under a human-readable name somewhere in the list,too